# Need clarification with the D3D11_FILTER enumeration (direct3d 11)

Tags: c++, direct3d

I just went to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that describes the D3D11_FILTER enumeration. But i just need some clarification with the description of one of the members.

One of the members in the enumeration is `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR` and it's description is `Use linear interpolation for minification, magnification, and mip-level sampling`

I think I understand what they mean by `minification` and `magnification`. They just mean that a texel(of a texture) can fit within one pixel or fit within multiple pixels. But i have a vague understanding about linear interpolation and how it relates to minification and magnification.

Can someone give a more accurate explanation about `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR`?

Comment: Nevermind, I think i figured it out.